# Listbox trigger it self when i add items

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

How to prevent SelectedIndexChanged to trigger for listbox when i add new items? It trigger for each item i add.

```
    private void lb_accounts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedProperty = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)lb_accounts.SelectedItem;
        fb.AccessToken = selectedProperty.Key;


        dynamic albums = fb.Get("/me/albums");

        Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (dynamic album in albums.data)
        {
            list.Add(album.id, album.name);
        }

        lb_albums.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);
        lb_albums.DisplayMember = "Value";
        lb_albums.ValueMember = "Key";
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear or your code snippet is irrelevant ? For which list box you want to prevent firing selected index change event?

Answer (score 0):

I have two listbox one Account and Album.
When i start the program, i connect to facebook and get all my accounts -> listbox
After that i select my account to get the albums for that account -> listbox

The problem is that when the i add items with lb_accounts.DataSource. DataSource trigger the event for SelectedIndexChanged for each item that i have added.

The code show you how i add item to a listbox and what the event looks like.